# Julia syntax highlighting in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I'm using the RStudio IDE to write R code. The editor seems to have additional syntax highlighting options for Julia which would be useful for my workflow. 
How may I select Julia syntax highlighting in RStudio?

Comment: Does it not do it automatically when you edit a `.jl` file? What does the RStudio documentation say?

Comment: Unfortunately no (RStudio version Version 1.0.136). Also, couldn't find any information on RStudio documentation.